# Reference slick instance from component (ngx-slick-carousel)

Tags: angular, typescript, slick.js

I am having a tough time trying to reference the instance of a ngx-slick-carousel from within my component. I have a couple of carousels in a page and I need to unslick and intilize them when I toggle between the two. The only way at the moment that I have been able to reference the slick carousel from my component is if I use the afterChange method and pass the event object from my template.

**For example**

**In Template**

```
<ngx-slick-carousel 
     class="carousel gallery-one" 
     #galleryOne="slick-carousel" 
     [config]="slideConfig" 
     (afterChange)="afterChange($event)">

     <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides.gallery" class="slide">
        <img src="{{slide.img}}">
     </div>
</ngx-slick-carousel>
```

**In Component**

```
afterChange(e) {
  console.log(e.slick);
}
```

How do I reference the slick instance like in the after change method from anywhere in my component? I tried a few ways and can't seem to get it to work. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template

```
<ngx-slick-carousel 
     class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-modal"
     #galleryOne="slick-carousel" 
     [config]="slideConfig" 
     (afterChange)="afterChange($event)">

     <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides.gallery" class="slide">
        <img src="{{slide.img}}">
     </div>
</ngx-slick-carousel>
```

In the component use below code to do the changes

`@ViewChild('slickModal') slickModal: SlickCarouselComponent;`

To unslick use below code

```
this.slickModal.unslick();
```

Re initialize use below code

```
this.slickModal.initSlick();
```

Move to particular slide use below code

```
this.slickModal.slickGoTo(0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Rahul, I was able to get it working thanks to your help. There was an error with one piece to your answer. #slickModal="slick-modal" throws and error There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "slick-modal" I had to use #galleryOne="slick-carousel" and use @ViewChild('galleryOne') galleryOne;

Comment: Thanks @GalacticRanger i updated the answer. U can mark it as answered if it sloved your problem

Comment: How to get the current active slides? slickModal.slickCurrentSlide seems not working..