# ngx-slick-carousel reinitialize slick after unslick in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am using Angular 7. 
I added `ngx-slick-carousel` as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel.

I adjusted `slideConfig` the way I want:

```
slideConfig = {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    speed: 1400,
    infinite: true,
    lazyLoad: "ondemand",
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 991,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
          autoplaySpeed: 2000,
          speed: 100
        }
      }, 
      {
        breakpoint: 575,
        settings: unslick
      }
    ]
  };
```

I want to `unslick` on viewport less than 575px so I added this in `slideConfig`. Configuration parameters are explained here: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

**Now, if viewport gets back greater than 575px I want to re-activate the slick.**

None of the solutions provided online worked.

Here for example, when I created the ViewChild, console prints undefined.
[Reference slick instance from component (ngx-slick-carousel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666260/reference-slick-instance-from-component-ngx-slick-carousel)

I referred also to solutions where jQuery is used to enabled slick again, but the jQuery functions are not identified in Angular.
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slick carousel element in html has a property `#slickModal="slick-carousel"`.

In our component, we import the `SlickCarouselComponent`

```
import { SlickCarouselComponent } from "ngx-slick-carousel";
```

and refer to the slick carousel in a variable

```
@ViewChild("slickModal") slickModal: SlickCarouselComponent;
```

now we import the `HostListener`

```
import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";
```

and in the following function, we detect the width of the viewport. If the viewport is greater than the `unslick` breakpoint, we re-initialize the slick.

```
@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
getScreenSize(event?) {
  if (this.slickModal !== undefined) {
     if (window.innerWidth > 575) {
       if (!this.slickModal.initialized) {
         this.slickModal.initSlick();
       }
     } else if (this.slickModal.initialized) {
       this.slickModal.unslick();
     }
  }
}
```

make sure to call this function in the constructor of your component

```
constructor() {
    this.getScreenSize();
}
```