# core.js:6156 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0201: No provider for SlickCarouselComponent found in NodeInjector

Tags: javascript, angular, slider, slick.js

I'm try to integrate ngx-slick-carousel in my project. I follow all steps with mention in official [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel) but it's throwing this error, also try this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666260/reference-slick-instance-from-component-ngx-slick-carousel/51666529) solution but no luck

[image]

my code

```
<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" 
                                
                                #slickModal="slick-carousel"
                                [config]="slideConfig" 
                                (init)="slickInit($event)"
                                (breakpoint)="breakpoint($event)"
                                (afterChange)="afterChange($event)"
                                (beforeChange)="beforeChange($event)">
                
            
                                <div  class="featured_slider slider">

                                    <!-- Slider Item -->
                                    <div class="featured_slider_item" ngxSlickItem>
                                        <div class="border_active"></div>
                                        <div class="product_item discount d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                                            <div class="product_image d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"><img src="assets/images/featured_1.png" alt=""></div>
                                            <div class="product_content">
                                                <div class="product_price discount">$225<span>$300</span></div>
                                                <div class="product_name"><div><a href="product.html">Huawei MediaPad...</a></div></div>
                                                <div class="product_extras">
                                                    <div class="product_color">
                                                        <input type="radio" checked name="product_color" style="background:#b19c83">
                                                        <input type="radio" name="product_color" style="background:#000000">
                                                        <input type="radio" name="product_color" style="background:#999999">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button class="product_cart_button">Add to Cart</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product_fav"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div>
                                            <ul class="product_marks">
                                                <li class="product_mark product_discount">-25%</li>
                                                <li class="product_mark product_new">new</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    </ngx-slick-carousel>
```

anyone have any idea about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you followed all steps mentioned here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel

Comment: yes! i followed all steps

Comment: can you please provide a stackblitz link ? I